# ActiveX cannot create object error when trying to convert PDF file to text file

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

When I try to convert my PDF file to text file, I encounter the following error:

> Involving Acrobat Error 429 : ActiveX cannot create object

My code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
    Dim AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim jsObj As Object
    Dim NewFileName As String

    Filename = "C:\Users\Boominathan\Desktop\test.pdf"

    NewFileName = "C:\file.txt"

    Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    AcroXAVDoc.Open Filename, "Acrobat"

    Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc

    Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject

    jsObj.SaveAs NewFileName, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

    AcroXAVDoc.Close False

    AcroXApp.Hide

    AcroXApp.Exit

End Sub
```

And the error is in the following line:

```
Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
```

Can you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: That error would seem to indicate that the class name `"AcroExch.App"` is not registered on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

That error would seem to indicate that the class name `"AcroExch.App"` is not registered on your machine.

Also, you've declared that object of type `Acrobat.AcroApp`, so you need to make up your mind which class you're using, because I think that will probably raise a Type 13 "Mismatch" error even if you do register the AcroExch.App class, because it's returning an object type that differs from the variable's declared type.

I'm not familiar with those object models but you could try:

```
Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("Acrobat.AcroApp")

Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("Acrobat.AcroAVDoc")
```

Comment: Thank you david for your answer. Can u please let me know how can i register the class name..?

Comment: You mean, reinstalling excel..?

Comment: No, whatever application is associated with `AcroEch.App`.

Comment: Which version(s) of Adobe Acrobat are currently installed on your machine? This thread suggests you may need Professional, and also that if you have multiple versions installed concurrently, that may be a problem. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/302392

Comment: i have acrobat 11.0... I dont have multiple versions installed but i dont have professional.. how can i get a professional version?

Comment: Well, software doesnt grow on trees... maybe you should purchase the professional version?

Comment: I guess software grows with tree.. Trees in data structure ;) and thanks for your response David